# Little integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\Big(\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}\Big)e^{-x}dx$ related to the Gompertz constant

Tags: integration, logarithms, exponential-function, improper-integrals, constants

It's a little result related to the [Gompertz constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GompertzConstant.html)

We have :

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\Big(\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}\Big)e^{-x}dx=-2G-2\frac{\operatorname{Ei(1)}}{e}$$
>   Where $G$ is the Gompertz constant and $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral .](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

This integral have an [simple antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangestart%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22ln%28%28x%C2%B2-2x%2B1%29%2F%28x%C2%B2%2B2x%2B1%29%29*e%5E%28-x%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangeend%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22) .But i look for a trick to solve this .

If you have nice ideas...

Thanks a lot for your contributions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple to manage this: For the undefined integration, just notice that

$$\log\left(\frac{x^2 - 2x + 1}{x^2+2x+1}\right) = \log\left(\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^2\right) = 2\log\bigg|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\bigg|$$

This being said, proceed as follows:

$\bullet$ First substitution: $x+1 = t ~~~~~~~ \text{d}x = \text{d}t$, your integral becomes

$$2e\int\ln\bigg|1 - \frac{2}{t}\bigg|e^{-t}\ \text{d}t$$

$\bullet$ Second substitution: $1 - \frac{2}{t} = z ~~~~~ \text{d}t = \frac{-2}{(1-z)^2}\text{d}z$, your integral becomes

$$2e\int \ln|z| e^{-\frac{2}{1-z}} \left(\frac{-2}{(1-z)^2}\right)\ \text{d}z$$

Now just notice that the last integral is nothing but

$$2e\int \ln|z| \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z} \left(-e^{-\frac{2}{1-z}}\right)\ \text{d}z$$

So you can integrate by parts easily.

Remember, from the theory of Special Functions, that

$$\int \frac{e^{-\frac{2}{1-z}}}{z}\ \text{d}z = \frac{\text{Ei}\left(2+\frac{2}{z-1}\right)}{e^2}-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{2}{z-1}\right)$$

**With extrema**

$\bullet$ During the first substitution, your extrema become $[0, +\infty) \to [1, +\infty)$

$\bullet$ During the second substitution, extrema become $[1, +\infty) \to [3, 1]$

I believe you can proceed alone from here.